# Use KrakenD CE + python 3.xx for gRPC-backend and manipulate responses from two or more backends

Tags: microservices, grpc, grpc-python, krakend

I am using a KrakenD community edition to implement an aggregator pattern where an endpoint: /abc is sent to KrakenD API gateway that will call the end-points /a, /b & /c. It will then combine the respective responses and return to /abc.

The issue is that the end-points /a, /b & /c are mapped to respective microservices and use gRPC calls. Is there a way KrakenD can handle this gRPC request manipulation?

PS: There is a gRPC transcoding plugin for KrakenD enterprise edition but not for the community edition. Is there a way to skip the transcoding part entirely i.e make a pure gRPC request.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, KrakenD can handle gRPC calls even with the community version.

You have to create a gRPC plugin with the contract of the backend you are consuming. Here's a guide (although old): https://www.krakend.io/blog/krakend-grpc-gateway-plugin/